# JavaScript return string with 2 char limit

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function which returns "Hello, World" string but the requirement is there should be only 2 char per line. In my function, I am using template literal and want to ignore newline \n. Can anyone suggest the best solution for it?

code::

```
f=_=>`H
el
lo
,w
or
ld
!`
```

Error ::

```
Expected: 'Hello, world!', instead got: 'H\nel\nlo\n,w\nor\nld\n!'
```

Comment: Please show what you have so far.

Comment: I updated and added the error which I am getting.

Comment: Why are you only allowed two characters per line (especially since you have seven on the first line)? I'm assuming code golf, but it could be for something else.

Comment: I am performing some task where 2 char are only allowed.

Comment: It is working as expected, two chars per line, isn't it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzYYr.png

Comment: You see the error above Which I am getting

Comment: Not really. I don't see any errors.

Comment: @lealcelderio His error is that the `\n`s are showing up in the result string.

Comment: Is JavaScript a requirement for the task, or can you use some other (industry standard) language?

Comment: JavaScript is the requirement

Comment: two chars per line, that is just ridiculous. However i just ran your code, and it works ?

Answer (score 1):

This method uses `substring()`:

**Javascript:**

```
const output = document.getElementById('demo');

function trimString(str, lineLength) {  
  for (var i=0; i<str.length; i+=lineLength) {
    output.innerHTML += str.substring(i, i+lineLength);
    output.innerHTML += "<br />";
  }
}

trimString('Hello World', 2);
```

**Don't forget the output:**

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**How it Works:** 
This will work by calling function `trimString(str, lineLength);`

  - *Replace `str` with a string surrounded in quotes.*

  - *Replace `lineLength` with the number of chars per line.*

Answer (score 0):

Your function could just use `replace` to replace the newlines:

```js
f=_=>`H
el
lo
,w
or
ld
!`

console.log(f().replace(/\n/g, ''))
```

Comment: So does your first line.

Comment: I mean inside a function.function that returns the string

Comment: then do it outside the function

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try:

```
function makeTwoCharPerLine(input) {
  return input.split('').map((char, index) => {
    return (index + 1) % 2 === 0 ? 
      `${char}${String.fromCharCode(13)}${String.fromCharCode(10)}` : char;
  }).join('');
}
```

Comment: it should be inside function

Comment: this function returns same output which I am getting in error

Comment: probably needs carriage return + line-feed. I updated my function

Answer (score 0):

Like it's syntactic parent, C, JavaScript allows you to escape newlines in the source with the backslash character:

```
f=
_=>
"\
H\
e\
l\
l\
o\
,\
W\
o\
r\
l\
d\
!\
";

document.write(f());
```

Here, every newline in the actual source is being ignored thanks to the `\` immediately before it, allowing the string to continue to another line in the source while remaining one line in the parent.